# ReactNativeBlobUtil crashes on Android with large files when getting base64

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, base64, react-native-blob-util

I am trying to get pdf's base64 to save it to my client's local device, and I do the following;

```
        ReactNativeBlobUtil.config({
          fileCache: false,
        })
          .fetch('GET', response?.data?.url)
          .then(async bookResponse => {

            const content = await bookResponse.base64(); //This line causes the crash
            //I am dividing the incoming content into 8MB Chunks, not relevant
            const splittedContent = splitBase64IntoChunks(content);
             ...Rest of the code below
              });
```

In ios, it seems to work fine even large pdf files like 100mb, however android is crashing when trying to get a large file such as 40mb.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the logcat output?

Comment: thats the catch, there is no log the app just crashes :<

Comment: I am sure that android studio gonna log something.